# Encountered either of 'bug' in Eclipse or some logic I don't understand

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public SortedArrayList<T> incrementItems(int increment) {
for(T sh: this) {
    Integer newValue = (Integer) sh + (Integer) increment;
    this.set(this.indexOf(sh), (T) newValue);
    }
return this;
}
```

This is my method, it simply goes through every element of the list and increments the value, it runs fine 80% of the time. However, if 1 is the "element" it increments it by double (again only sometimes).

I've given some examples below:

```
    SortedArrayList<Integer> L1 = new SortedArrayList<Integer>();
    L1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,3,6,1,6,6,7,8,11,11,14,15,20,20));
    System.out.println(L1.incrementItems(10));
```

Output is: 
`[21, 13, 16, 21, 16, 16, 17, 18, 11, 11, 24, 25, 30, 30]`

```
    SortedArrayList<Integer> L1 = new SortedArrayList<Integer>();
    L1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,3,6,1,6,6,7,8,11,11,14,15,20,20));
    System.out.println(L1.incrementItems(9));
```

Output is:`[10, 12, 24, 10, 15, 15, 16, 17, 29, 29, 23, 15, 20, 20]`

```
    SortedArrayList<Integer> L1 = new SortedArrayList<Integer>();
    L1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,3,6,1,6,6,7,8,11,11,14,15,20,20));
    System.out.println(L1.incrementItems(4));
```

Output is:`[5, 19, 10, 5, 10, 10, 7, 12, 15, 11, 18, 15, 24, 24]`

Some numbers trigger this to happen, others don't. So again I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the Eclipse IDE.

You are invoking `indexOf` on your `List`, which will retrieve the first element matching.

Every time.

See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list[...]

So if you are looping and `1` comes across twice, `indexOf` will return the first position of `1`, and the element will be incremented.

What happens next is based on the further items in your `List`: if a match is found for the incremented item later in your iteration, the same item will be incremeneted again while the latter occurrences will be left untouched.

As an off-topic issue, you seem to be misusing generics here: your `SortedArrayList` class accepts any kind of type parameters, yet its `incrementItems` only assumes values will be `Integer`.

**Note**

If you're using Java 8, you can leverage the `map` functionality of streams to easily project all your `List` elements to their incremented value.

For instance:

```
// this will generate a new `List` with incremented elements
List<Integer> incremented = originalList
    .stream()
    .map(x -> Integer.sum(x, increment))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are stuck with pre-Java 8 idioms, you can create a new `List` with the code such as:

```
List<Integer> incremented = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i: originalList) {
    incremented.add(i + increment);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will get the index of 1 twice? I think it's rather that it increments 1 by 10 to 11, and then when it reaches 11 in the list indexOf(11) will again return the first index because that element is now 11.

Comment: I know, the assignment calls for creating a generic class, but in this specific case, we have to make a method that basically doesn't make sense in the case of anything but integers in the list. Hence the crazy casting.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that is actually way more accurate. Let me amend.

Comment: Also to my knowledge, it's getting the index of the element, not the value. If it was doing what you said it wouldn't work in the case of incrementing by 9? Also the results for 4 are a little wild. but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @AfroYak it is indeed getting the index of the value, then sets the incremented value at the given index. The issue here is basically tied to having values in your `List` that are equal to the sum of a value with lower index and the increment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think I understand where the issue is, I fixed it by simply using another variable as an index counter.

Comment: @AfroYak yes, indexed iteration is another option too.